# CORB blocking javascript POST to NodeJS backend on c9 platform

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-cloud9, cross-origin-read-blocking

I'm working on a pretty straightforward project for school. Me and my teammate chose AWS-Cloud9 as our platform, which I learned to use on the fly as we progressed. My job is the scripting. I have a NodeJS backend using Express to query my DB, and I have client side JS to send a post with form data to the backend. For reasons I don't understand, I'm getting the following error: 
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response /*Address of my project*/search.js with MIME type text/html

I've been all up and down the internet for the last 8 hours, and I can't find a solution that works. I tried adding the cors package to my backend, I tried manipulating both the client side and backend headers

Client Side

```
document.getElementById("search_form").onsubmit = function(event) {
    var val = document.getElementById("search_bar").textContent;
    var data = JSON.stringify(val);

    var fetchParams = {
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'User-Agent': 'JDevo/1.0',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: data,
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors'
    };

    window.fetch('/*c9 address of my project*//queryDB.js/', fetchParams)
        .then(res => function(res) {
            document.getElementById("main_page").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("results_page").style.display = "block";
            if (res.status !== 200) {
                document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML = "There was a problem with the response";
                return;
            }
            var games = JSON.parse(res.body);
            document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML = games;
        });
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Backend

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require("express");
var cors = require('cors');

var app = express();
app.use(cors());

var con = mysql.createConnection({/*DB params*/
});

app.post('/*c9 project address*//queryDB.js/', function(req, res) {
    //var searchItem = req.body.query;
    var searchItem = 'sekiro';/*testing backend with locked value to make sure a response is being sent*/

    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Connected");

        var sql = 'Select * FROM gamesMerged WHERE gameName LIKE "%' + searchItem + '%";';

        con.query(sql, function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            res.status(200).json(JSON.stringify(result));
        });
    });

});
app.listen(3000);
```

The expectations would be the post successfully pulled a response, which would then lead to the main page div hiding as the results page div pops up, with the "dummy" div serving as a response area to display either a message indicating that the backend failed it's request, or otherwise display the response object. This is a testing scenario, once I'm passed this hurdle, I'll be parsing successfully returned response objects and manipulating the response page more accurately

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out. Upon further review I discovered that my html script tag's src attribute was incorrectly written